# Having issues with fread and fwrite when writing some characters and a struct to a file and reading them back

Tags: c++, c, fwrite, fread

I want to write three characters to a file, then a struct, then one more character. 
Finally I would like to read the character before the struct, the struct itself, the character after the struct and display them on the screen.

```
 struct stuff{
   int a;
   int b;
};

int main(){

  FILE * fp = fopen("input.txt", "w+");
  char charA = 'z';
  char charB = 's';
  char charC = 'q';
  char charD = 'e';

  //create a struct of type stuff
  stuff s;
  s.a = 123;
  s.b = 2111;

 //fwrite three first chars
  fwrite(&charA, 1, sizeof(char), fp);
  fwrite(&charB, 1, sizeof(char), fp);
  fwrite(&charC, 1, sizeof(char), fp);
  //fwrite the struct
  fwrite(&s, 1, sizeof(struct stuff), fp);
  //fwrite the last char
  fwrite(&charD, 1, sizeof(char), fp);

  //read the char before the struct, the struct itself,
  // and the char after the struct
  char expectedCharC;
  stuff expectedStructS;
  char expectedCharD;

  fseek(fp, sizeof(struct stuff) + sizeof(char), SEEK_END);
  fread(&expectedCharC, 1, sizeof(char), fp);
  fread(&expectedStructS, 1, sizeof(struct stuff), fp);
  fseek(fp, sizeof(char)*3 + sizeof(struct stuff), SEEK_SET);
  fread(&expectedCharD, 1, sizeof(char), fp);

  cout<<expectedCharC<<" "<<expectedStructS.a<<" ";
  cout<<expectedStructS.b<<" "<<expectedCharD<<endl;

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Instead of this result:

`q 123 2111 e`

I get this result:

`4197174 0 e`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm writing bytes to the file, reading them back and displaying them on the screen. What goes wrong?

thank you in advance

Comment: `fseek(fp, sizeof(struct stuff) + sizeof(char), SEEK_END);` wrong

Comment: No flushing issues here? The expected input seems off by 1 (when rather freely interpreting what is stated), which *may* be caused by file buffering of that last `fwrite`.

Comment: you are right, I'm missing one char in the first read, plus from the other answers I'm using the entire thing wrong, I can't believe I wasted my entire day for this. I'm working on a bigger system that had some bugs, it took me one day to convince myself that I need to make sure I know how `fread` and `fwrite` work until I finally ended up creating this code. Now I'm banging my head against the wall for not doing it earlier. Today is a yet another day where I see how stupid I really am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, lots of problems in your code. Let's tackle them one by one.

1. As mentioned by unwind, the mode you're using to open the file seems to be incorrect as to what you're trying to do. For one, you're trying to **read** from a file that is opened for **write-only**.
2. You're using `fwrite` wrongly. It goes `fwrite(pointer to data, size of each data, number of data, FILE pointer);`.
3. You're using `fseek` wrongly. I see you're confused with the `offset` parameter. This offset defines a **signed distance** from the `origin` specified as the last argument to `fseek`. Therefore, if you're at `SEEK_END`, you should be moving backwards by having your `offset` be a negative number.

I've done these changes myself and now it works. Output: `q 123 2111 e`

Here's a nice little [website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio) for you too. Helped me with your problem.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

First, as has been pointed out, you must open the file in binary
mode.  Even then, just dumping the bytes of a `struct` means
that you won't be able to read it correctly some time in the
future.  But as long as you're reading from the same process, it
should be OK.

The real problem is what you are doing with all of the `fseek`:
before the first `fread`, you do an `fseek` beyond the end of
the file.  Any read from that position is guaranteed to fail.
You really should check the status of the file, and ensure that
the `fread` has succeeded before accessing any of the values you
read.  If it failed, accessing the variables (at least those in
`stuff`) is undefined behavior; most likely, you'll get some
random garbage.

Your first `fseek` should probably be to the beginning of the file, or
else:

```
fseek( fp, -(sizeof( stuff ) + 4), SEEK_BEG);
```

If you've just read the struct, then the second `fseek` is
unnecessary as well.  (In your case, it means that the final
`'e'` is correctly read.)

Answer (score 0):

You must open your file in binary mode for this to work.

```
FILE * fp = fopen("input.txt", "wb+");
                                 ^
                                 |
                                blam!
```

Your wanted result is also a bit unclear, shouldn't it start with the three characters `'z'`, `'s'` and `'q'`, and then have the integers? Note that the integers are likely to appear byte-swapped if you're on a little-endian machine.

To help debug the code, you should add return-value checking to all I/O calls, since I/O can fail. Also note that `sizeof (char)` is always `1`, so it's not very beneficial to write it like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same result. I'm reading the previous two characters as well but I'm not printing them.
I'm compiling with the following options:

`g++ -O3 -std=c++0x main.cpp`